# To express a coming event, is "go" being used correctly here?

Tags: meaning

To express a coming event, I am aware of the famous "the winter is coming".

She is saying [as far as the tests or exams go you want to know what's the material](https://youtu.be/iSV9uohbCjQ?t=298)

is "go" being used correctly here?

Comment: _Go_ has multiple meanings. I think she means "As  far as the exams are concerned".

Comment: This is idiomatic phrasing in conversation to narrow the focus of what you are about to say. For example,  “Spending a holiday with a two-year-old is not ideal but, as far as the weather goes, it’s been lovely.”